How to use a Pixi virtual environment to run a Jupyter notebook in VSCode
I'm trying to use Pixi as a Conda replacement. However, when I try to select the Pixi environment in VSCode's 'Python: Select Interpreter' command, it's not listed.
Any advice on how to get VSCode to recognise the Pixi environment?
I've tried manually specifying the Python path, but that hasn't worked.

Didn't work for me either, even after installing the Pixi VSCode extension.
Solved after adding ipykernel and pip to the pixi environment:
pixi add ipykernel pip


Pixi support for Visual Studio Code to manage Pixi projects
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jjjermiah.pixi-vscode

This worked, but after I ran pixi add ipykernel pip as suggested by @carolient
